# Find installed android applications for a different user

Tags: android

We have an Enterprise Android application that runs under the work profile.  We would like to check to see if an application is installed under the "normal" user profile on the device.

Just wondering if there is anyway way to do this at all?  The PackageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName) only returns applications that are installed under the work profile (even setting the  tag in the manifest file).

Is this possible at all?

Comment: No this isn't possible without rooting the device. A users environment is completely self contained by design.